# How to toggle full-screen mode in after effect

Tags: window, adobe, keyboard-shortcuts, after-effects

What is the keyboard shortcut for toggling full-screen and windowed mode in Adobe After Effect (Creative Cloud)?

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> for macOS.

Answer taken from Adobe's (somewhat cryptic) documentation on [windowing shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html#panels_viewers_workspaces_and_windows_keyboard_shortcuts):

| Result | Windows | macOS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Resize application window or floating window to fit screen. (Press again to resize window so that contents fill the screen.) | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> | <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> |